# WebHostBuilder error encrypted application.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, asp.net-core

I have created an `AddEncryptedJson` extension to `IConfigurationBuilder`.  I use it the following way in my startup.cs:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddEncryptedJson("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
Configuration = builder.Build();
```

It encrypts the appsettings.json file if it has not been already encrypted, and decrypts it to read it's settings.  Everything in Startup.cs is working as expected.

However, when execution jumps back out to Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

it throws a `System.FormatException`:

```
System.FormatException: 'Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '0': '�(�<�G#[v��_K���'.'
```

Is Program.cs also looking for appsettings.json and attempting to read it?  How do I get around this?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `.UseApplicationInsights()` extension is the one that was trying to access the encrypted file.  Removing this from the pipeline resolved this.